# regex to remove periods/fullstops from string but not from inside numbers

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking for a regex to remove periods/fullstops from string but not from inside numbers and replace with space

```
$str1 = 'some.text.1.2.3.more.text';
$str2 = preg_replace('/(?<!\d)[._](?![._\d])/', ' ', $str1);
```

the above snippet nearly does the job but fails to remove the first period/fullstop before a number resulting in string being:
`some text.1.2.3 more text`
but I want
`some text 1.2.3 more text`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. What you want is to replace dots/underscores that are either not preceded by a number, or not followed by one:

```
$str2 = preg_replace('/((?<!\d)[._])|([._](?![._\d]))/', ' ', $str1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this one. It looks for non-digit at left or non digit at right before replacing the characters.

```
$str2 = preg_replace('/(?<=\D)[._]|[._](?=\D)/', ' ', $str1);
```

Comment: @HamZa yeah. it can't remove the `.`. That case it will work after changing the lookahead into `(?=\D|$)`.

Answer (score 1):

An other way to do that:

```
$str2 = preg_replace('~\d[._\d]*\d(*SKIP)(?!)|[._]~', ' ', $str1);
```

The first part always fails due to the `(?!)` *(an always false assertion)* and the `(*SKIP)` backtracking control verb forces the regex engine to not retry the substring matched before.

Comment: Why don't you use `(*FAIL)` ? Or is it just a preference ?

Comment: @HamZa: thanks for the edit! No special reason, to change or to make it shorter.